# How to download/save json data from api server and update it every spacific time automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, save

Hi guys I'm still beginner at using node.js
so I want to know if is there a method to download from the below server

https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/ ID here /

I need to save the json data for around 500 IDs and update them on specific times if that do-able.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Another option is that you will schedule a chrono from cpanel.
It is an option that allows you to execute a certain command every certain time.

Comment: Great, I'm going to look it up, but I need to know how to save it first

Comment: Tal vez te funcione esto var Request = require("request");

Request.get("http://httpbin.org/ip", (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    console.dir(JSON.parse(body));
});

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'request'
what module do I need?